# Is this set a Hilbert space itself?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be an Hilbert space and let $\mathscr{C}\subset\mathscr{H}$ be a convex subset.

Let me define

$$ \mathscr{A}:=\{F:\mathscr{C}\to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ s.t.  $F$ is continuous, Gateaux differentiable and convex}\},$$

i.e. the space of the continuous, Gateaux differentiable and convex functionals defined on a convex subset of a Hilbert space.

My question: is $\mathscr{A}$ a Hilbert space itself? If yes (or not), how to prove this?

Could someone give me some hint? A reference will be appreciated, too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking if there is some norm that makes $\mathscr{A}$ into a Hilbert space?

Comment: @copper.hat exactly. If it will be also closed, it will be a Hilbert sapce itself (I guess).

Comment: You need some sort of norm to start with before closed makes sense.

Comment: @copper.hat, sure, so I completely agree with your first comment.

Comment: It is trivially false, if $F$ nonlinear then $-F$ is not convex and so $\mathscr{A}$ cannot be a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said by TSF, this is false in most interesting situations. Indeed, if there exist $x_1, x_2 \in C$, $x_1 \ne x_2$,
we can construct a nonlinear convex function,
i.e.,
$$ f := ( x \mapsto \langle x^*, x\rangle^2),$$
where $x^* \in H^*$ separates $x_1$ and $x_2$.
Then, $f$ is convex, continuous and Fréchet differentiable. However, $-f$ is not convex and, therefore, $A$ is not a subspace.

However,
if $C$ contains less than two elements, $A$ is one-dimensional or zero-dimensional and, therefore, a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what do you mean with "interesting situations"? What $x^*$ and $H^*$ denote? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Interesting situation" means that $C$ does contain more than one point. And $H^*$ is the (topological) dual space of $H$.

Comment: gerw, may I ask about linear functions which are continuous, Gateaux differentiable and convex? At last in that case we deal with a vector space?

Comment: A linear, continuous function is automatically Gateaux differentiable and convex. And the linear and continuous functions form a vector space.